# Menu Created in Python Using While Loop Doesn't Exit When Wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have been trying to create a simple menu that exits the program when the user presses 4. The menu works if the user immediately selects 4, but if the user selects other options before pressing 4, the while loop doesn't break and the menu continues. Any ideas how I can change it so the menu does exit properly?

```
def main(): 
     print('''
           Welcome to Grade Central
           [1] - Enter Grades
           [2] - Remove Student
           [3] - Student Average Grades
           [4] - Exit
           \n
           ''')

     action = int(input("What would you like to do today? \n"))
     if action == 1:
         print(1)
     elif action == 2:
         print(2)
     elif action == 3:
         print(3)
     elif action == 4:
         print("The program has been exited")
     else:
         print("Invalid input! Please select an option")
     return action

while main() != 4:
     main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to stop the program or just exit the loop?

Comment: I would suggest going with argparse module in python to take inputs and then keep the while loop inside the main() function and use ``` break``` to exit .

Comment: Your program doesn't update the condition of the while loop. The body of your while loop isn't feeding back... I suggest store the return of `main()` in a variable check that variable and update the same variable in the body of the while loop

Comment: I was attempting to exit the loop, there wouldn't be anything else to the code that would run without the menu so I think exiting the loop would be the same as exiting the program for me. Thank you for the help! That's done excatly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a variable outside of the function that is set to whatever is returned from the function and have that getting checked by the while loop, that should work.

```
def main():
    print('''
           Welcome to Grade Central
           [1] - Enter Grades
           [2] - Remove Student
           [3] - Student Average Grades
           [4] - Exit
           \n
           ''')

    action = int(input("What would you like to do today? \n"))
    if action == 1:
        print(1)
    elif action == 2:
        print(2)
    elif action == 3:
        print(3)
    elif action == 4:
        print("The program has been exited")
    else:
        print("Invalid input! Please select an option")
    print(action)
    return action

returned_action = 0
while returned_action != 4:
    returned_action = main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main(): 
     print('''
           Welcome to Grade Central
           [1] - Enter Grades
           [2] - Remove Student
           [3] - Student Average Grades
           [4] - Exit
           \n
           ''')

     action = int(input("What would you like to do today? \n"))
     if action == 1:
         print(1)
     elif action == 2:
         print(2)
     elif action == 3:
         print(3)
     elif action == 4:
         print("The program has been exited")
     else:
         print("Invalid input! Please select an option")
     return action

action = main()
while action != 4:
     action = main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some form of input validation in your program.

```py
def main():
    action = get_input()
    # do something with action

def get_input():
    action = 0
    while action not in range(1,5):
        try:
            action = int(input('What would you like to do today?\n'))
            if action not in range(1,5):
                print('Action not recognized.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter an integer.')

    return action
```

This allows you to check if the user input was an integer and/or it is an action that you handle. It will keep asking the user, "What would you like to do today?" until the input is valid. You can modify the range to handle more values, and you can modify the error messages to display a help output.

Answer (score 0):

You call main() twice for each loop and only test one of the return values.

Use this instead:

```
while main() != 4:
     pass
```

pass is a command that does nothing.